# Symfony file upload edit

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Im using Symfony 3.3 and configured a file upload like in the handbook.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

When editing my entity in a form, after the submission of the form, the image property (like in example "Brochure") is "null", even if set it before submit.

```
$entity->setBrochure(new File($this->getParameter('brochures_directory').'/'.$entity->getBrochure()));
```

So it is not possible to decide if the user really want to remove the image or if he wants to keep it.

Did I forgot something or how is it possible to correctly handle the image?

Thank you for your answers!

Best!

Answer (score 1):

It's due to HTML specifications: a file input can't be pre-filled.

A solution is to put another input submit with a different name (different than the default one). Only the button/input "clicked" by the user will be sent.

Detect it in the request; if exist, delete your file data.

And, in your view, display the original name (and/or size, type... whatever your want) near the input file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I just added a field with the id of the file saved in the database, this is used instead of input type "file", if there is no new image uploaded!

Best!

Comment: Can you please post your solution?